# magento change top links hellowired theme

Tags: magento

I am new to magento.I have used `hellowired` theme of magento 1.6. In this theme at the top of the page there are top links like My account, My cart etc. How do i change the toplinks in hellowired theme of magento?

Answer (score 0):

Search `top.links` inside of the whole .xml files that reside in **layout** directory. You will see xml nodes that related with different link. For instance, in the `customer.xml`, there is "My Account" section.